# System Side C Vs C?

Tags: linux, operating-system, embedded

I tried searching for the word "System Side programmer" or "System Side C" but did not get any good info.
Can someone explain me the difference between System Side C and C and 
System Programmer vs System Side Programmer.
Would be great if some could provide links to study System Side C focused on Linux Kernel.
Thanks in Advance

UPDATE: System Side C is the C language code that is used to build the Operating system. Eg: how a page table is implemented inside an OS using Struct.

Comment: Do you mean differences between C programming in kernel side and userspace side?

Comment: @alireza_fn What would you do when if i tell you to learn System Side C focused on Linux kernel?

Comment: The programming syntax of C is same, but available functions are difference. You cannot use some ANSI functions in kernel like printf()

Comment: So basically it is programming the system calls? 
i mean using interrupts. What platform can i use to practice this kind of C programming?

Comment: Not actually. Linux Kernel provides a large set of functions for modules so you don't have to mess with interrupts. You should try reading some linux kernel programming books then you should start programming kernel modules.

Comment: thanks alireza_fn but again the set of functions is like printf() right? I hope there is someone here who works as System Side Programmer. May be they would know the exact meaning or difference? :/ Cause i really need it

Comment: use votes for thanking. I posted an answer, it should be complete enough.

Comment: Are you familiar with Linux system programming (application-side) using [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) ? Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). If you need to code some kernel modules, there are several books on it, and also http://kernelnewbies.org/

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i have little knowledge of Unix System calls. 
And you mentioned (application-side) as System programming. Could you tell me what (System-Side) mean then?

Comment: "System-Side" is ambiguous but might mean "Kernel-Side" i.e. *inside* the Linux kernel (e.g. in kernel modules).

Comment: If i tell you that we can use Assemble, C, C++. Does that help in figuring out what it is? ie Kernel Modules or System programming.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch.

Answer (score 3):

C language syntax is same in both but available functions are different. Linux kernel provides many ANSI C functions which are needed like string manipulation functions but it doesn't provide useless functions in kernel programming like scanf or printf,... . 
Linux kernel also provides functions for interacting with kernel subsystems like sysfs, devices, filesystems, IPC, ... . You should read the official linux kernel api documentation here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/

Comment: Thank you Alireza, i'm afraid i dont have enough reputation to vote.

Comment: @user3815757 for [up-voting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) you need a reputation >= 15. Your current 17 > 15